# Electromagnetic Dipole, elementary question

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits

Question Of Understanding to the Dipole: does the coil have an induction current running contrary to the current coming from the Capacitor, which role plays this current in the dipole?

Otherwise, a general question about the capacitor: Which of the two Plates is negative and which positively charged (in Relation to the current direction)?

Comment: I interpret "electromagnetic dipole" to mean a dipole antenna, which is simply wire(s) in a certain configuration. It does not have the discrete components you mention. (Although certain antenna matching circuits have those components, or one might talk about inductance and capacitance of the antenna wires). If you have a capacitor and inductor, perhaps a circuit diagram, along with a stated purpose, would help.